# How to create nested object in PHP

Tags: php

```
$array = (object)array(
    'name' => 'David',
    'friends' => (object)array(
        (object)array('name' => 'Max'),
        (object)array('name' => 'Jian')
    )
);

var_dump($array);
```

I want to learn how to use stdClass function to get the same result, don't want to use (object) before each array, convert cause some resource, and I know `json_encode` and `json_decode` can make it, just want to learn how stdClass make nested structure.

Comment: How much PHP have you programmed?

Comment: Simplest solution (aside from casting to `object`):  Create an array, `json_encode` it, and `json_decode` the resulting JSON.  :P  Next closest:  Create an array and then recursively objectify it.

Comment: What do you mean? I mean @EricHerlitz

Comment: You can't. If the json hack bothers you, wrap it in another function incase you find a better implementation later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a trick with [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) to easily get this:

```
$array = array(
  'foo' => array('bar'=>'a', 'baz'=>'b'),
  'feo' => 'bee',
  'boo' => array('a'=>array('x', 'y'), 'b'=>array('z'))
);


$object = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

*Update*

If you don't want to use JSON function, you can handle your array recursively, like:

```
function getStdObject(array $data)
{
   foreach($data as &$item)
   {
      if(is_array($item))
      {
         $item = getStdObject($item);
      }
   }
   return (object)$data;
}

$array = array(
  'foo' => array('bar'=>'a', 'baz'=>'b'),
  'feo' => 'bee',
  'boo' => array('a'=>array('x', 'y'), 'b'=>array('z'))
);
$object = getStdObject($array));
```

Answer (score 1):

This class is available at: http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.construct.php#111192

```
/**
 * @author Iltar van der Berg
 * @version 2.0.0
 */
class RecursiveArrayObject extends ArrayObject
{
    /**
     * overwrites the ArrayObject constructor for 
     * iteration through the "array". When the item
     * is an array, it creates another self() instead
     * of an array
     * 
     * @param Array $array data array
     */
    public function __construct(Array $array)
    {    
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)){
                $value = new static($value);
            }
            $this->offsetSet($key, $value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns Array when printed (like "echo array();")
     * instead of an error
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __ToString()
    {
        return 'Array';
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$a = array(
    'one' => array(
            'hello','world'
        ),
    'two' => array(
            'lorem','ipsum'
        )
);

var_dump($a);

$o = new RecursiveArrayObject($a);

var_dump($o);
```

Yields:

```
array (size=2)
  'one' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'hello' (length=5)
      1 => string 'world' (length=5)
  'two' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'lorem' (length=5)
      1 => string 'ipsum' (length=5)

object(RecursiveArrayObject)[1]
  public 'one' => 
    object(RecursiveArrayObject)[2]
      string 'hello' (length=5)
      string 'world' (length=5)
  public 'two' => 
    object(RecursiveArrayObject)[3]
      string 'lorem' (length=5)
      string 'ipsum' (length=5)
```